# I need to return daily SUM from two columns covering 7 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to return daily SUM from two columns covering 7 months
I am attempting to do this, but this is way too time consuming. Is there a method to return these in sequence incremented one day at a time?

```
select SUM(TotalBet)SALES, SUM(TotalWin)PRIZES from play nolock where CurrentDate between '1/1/2013 07:00:00' and '1/2/2013 7:00:00'

select SUM(TotalBet)SALES, SUM(TotalWin)PRIZES from play nolock where CurrentDate between '1/2/2013 07:00:00' and '1/3/2013 7:00:00'

select SUM(TotalBet)SALES, SUM(TotalWin)PRIZES from play nolock where CurrentDate between '1/3/2013 07:00:00' and '1/4/2013 7:00:00'

select SUM(TotalBet)SALES, SUM(totalbet)PRIZES from play nolock where CurrentDate between '1/4/2013 07:00:00' and '1/5/2013 7:00:00'

select SUM(TotalBet)SALES, SUM(TotalWin)PRIZES from play nolock where CurrentDate between '1/5/2013 07:00:00' and '1/6/2013 7:00:00'

select SUM(TotalBet)SALES, SUM(TotalWin)PRIZES from play nolock where CurrentDate between '1/6/2013 07:00:00' and '1/7/2013 7:00:00'
```

Comment: Is the CurrentDate column indexed ? If not, consider indexing it, this will increase performance for such requests

Comment: CurrentDate is indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an aggregation.  The key is to convert the `datetime` to a `date`.  To get the right date, subtract 7 hours:

```
select cast(CurrentDate - 7.0/24 as date) as thedate,
       SUM(TotalBet) as SALES, SUM(totalbet) as PRIZES
from play nolock
group by cast(CurrentDate - 7.0/24 as date)
order by 1;
```

Comment: I just had an update where the timeframe needs to be from 7:00:00 to 6:59:59

Answer (score 1):

Use a [numbers table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx) to generate your dates, and then join to the table and group by the day. You could go straight to the table, but if you have missing dates (say, a holiday) they won't show in the results without a numbers table.

```
SELECT 
   D.Date, SUM(TotalBet) as Sales, SUM(TotalBet) as Prizes
FROM (
   SELECT DATEADD(dd, CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01 07:00'), Number) as Date
   FROM dbo.NumbersTable(0, 210) --210 days
) as D
LEFT OUTER JOIN Play as P ON
   P.CurrentDate >= D.Date AND P.CurrentDate < D.Date
GROUP BY
   D.Date
```

You'll also (probably) want to not use BETWEEN, as you could end up with duplicates on the boundaries (BETWEEN is inclusive on both sides).

Comment: I realize that now. I updated the request to run from 7:00:00 to 6:59:59

Comment: @KevinW - you'll still miss milliseconds. Just do it the "right" way and use a strict `<` for one side. Never use BETWEEN for production work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to guess a bit at what you're after, but I think that the below works:

```
select
  AdminDate,
  SUM(TotalBet) SALES,
  SUM(totalbet) PRIZES --Unless the DB has a CS collation, this is identical to the above
from
    (select
        DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,DATEADD(hour,-7,CurrentDate)),0) as AdminDate,
        TotalBet
    from play
    ) t
where AdminDate >= '20130101' and AdminDate < '20130801'
group by AdminDate
order by AdminDate asc
```

(Note that this will not be able to benefit from using indexes though - if that matters, consider adding `AdminDate` as a computed column to the table)

The key is to create this `AdminDate` column, which first subtracts 7 hours from `CurrentDate`, and then removes the time component from the result - this has the effect that every datetime value from 7am today until just before 7am tomorrow will be, for administrative purposes, treated as having happened "today". Once we have these `AdminDate`s, it's easy to perform a `GROUP BY` on those to find the totals for each `AdminDay`.

---

**NB** I've also removed `nolock` from the query since it wasn't doing what you thought it was doing. In your original query, it's introducing an alias for the `play` table called `nolock`. If you actually **need** the query to not perform any locking on the table, you want to use `WITH (NOLOCK)`

Comment: I cannot edit the actual data, adding a column is not an option.